# Lookup Name Property from the ID in the database

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I currently have the below snippet of code that works fine for Dropdown list. I would like to do the same thing but have it as a TextBoxFor field instead. I am utilizing bloodhound bootstrap plugin and replacing my dropdown list with the bootstrap plugin.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CaseMaster.InvoiceStatusId, new SelectList(Model.InvoiceStatus, "Id", "Name"), "Select Status", new { @class = "form-control col-sm" })
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'input field'? Do you mean a `TextBoxFor`?

Comment: Yes that is correct, TextBoxFor.